# Give access for user2 to schema1 in Postgresql

Tags: postgresql, permissions, search-path

There is a table with several schemas (users).
I want to give access for one scheme (user) to another scheme.
In order to this user has access to the tables of another scheme.

Scheme and user 1: **ctl_r1**
Scheme and user 2: **check_b2**

**I want user2 to have access to scheme1**

I open the console under the admin and run the script:

```
set role db_admin;

GRANT ALL ON schema ctl_r1 TO check_b2;
GRANT USAGE ON SCHEMA "ctl_r1" TO "check_b2";
GRANT SELECT, UPDATE, INSERT, DELETE ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA "ctl_r1" TO "check_b2";
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON ALL SEQUENCES IN SCHEMA "ctl_r1" TO "check_b2";
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA "ctl_r1" TO "check_b2";
GRANT EXECUTE ON ALL FUNCTIONS IN SCHEMA "ctl_r1" TO "check_b2";
GRANT EXECUTE ON ALL ROUTINES IN SCHEMA "ctl_r1" TO "check_b2";
GRANT EXECUTE ON ALL PROCEDURES IN SCHEMA "ctl_r1" TO "check_b2";

alter role check_b2 set search_path = check_b2, ctl_r1;
```

After that, here, in the admin console, I run command:

```
select rolconfig
from pg_roles
where rolname = 'check_b2';
```

and I see 2 schemes in search_path:

```
rolconfig
-----------------------------
{search_path=check_b2,ctl_r1}
```

Next, I open the console of the user2 (check_b2) and check the command:

```
show search_path;
```

```
search_path
-----------
check_b2
```

-for some reason I see only 1 schema in the search_path.
And therefore, of course, the user2 does not see the table of scheme1.

But after some time (about 10 minutes) I run again:

```
show search_path;
```

```
search_path
----------------
check_b2, ctl_r1
```

-now i see 2 schemas in the answer.
And now the user2 sees the tables of scheme1 and has access to them.

Then, after some time, the `show search_path;`
again gives only 1 scheme in response.

Please can you explain, why this is happening? And **how can I give access for the user2 to the scheme1 one time and forever ?**

Comment: `search_path` has nothing to do with permissions. It seems like you are using a connection pool and the second query actually uses a different, new, database session.

Answer (score 2):

You can permanently add the path by altering the user.

```sql
ALTER ROLE username SET search_path TO "$user", public, test;
```

As the previous command takes effect at the next login only, you can apply it immediately by running

```sql
SET search_path TO "$user", public, test;
```